# Creation of an unique link to an outlook e-mail

Tags: outlook-addin, tracking, outlook-web-addins

**Background:**
Since all tasks, are more or less assigned per E-mail I want track the e-mail via a link in other programs (Project, Planner, Word, Excel, OneNote, ect). This should be possible via the globally unique identifier GUID of the Outlook message & the Outlook URL Protocol.
I can only find instructions on this for older versions - which does not work.
BTW: Tracking via searching on subjects is a pain, since subject changes and conversation history can be long.
**Question:**

How do generate a link to the e-mail in outlook 365 which is unique and can be opened in other programs (Project, Planner, Word, Excel, OneNote, ect)?

**There are other ways possible? Add-in?**

This should be It should be possible!

However I do not know how it works with Office 365 --> Pls see following website:

https://www.davidtan.org/create-hyperlinks-to-outlook-messages-folders-contacts-events/

*Excerpt out of it:*

The Windows operating system recognizes the outlook: tag and whenever it sees that it’s part of a link, it triggers outlook to do something. Depending how you format the hyperlink, you can open messages, folders, contacts and meetings stored in outlook from websites, documents (Word, OpenOffice etc), Excel spreadsheets and powerpoint presentations stored either locally or even over a shared network.

**How To Link To Outlook Items:**

1. Outlook Paths

Outlook provides a way to link to any Outlook item using a URL. It can be “path based” like this:

– Outlook:Inbox\
  – Outlook:Personal Folders\Contacts\~John Doe

2. Outlook GUID

You can link to a globally unique identifier (GUID) that is created for an item and doesn’t change when you rename or move it:

– Outlook:000000000EAE44933247899468AC478B81C0BANDHEWR324

It is best to use the GUID URL since you don’t have to worry about changes breaking the link. 
If you are after a outlook message, all you have to do is select that message in outlook, and then left-click on the linker icon on the lower right of the taskbar so that the link will get copied. Next, you will just have to paste it somewhere. It works the same way for contacts and even calendar events.

By default, the copied link will be something like this

Email subject here

If you are building a webpage using HTML, then you can merely copy and paste that code to the HTML file, and maybe just changing the link text.

However, if you are working in Excel, what is important is only the part that says:

Outlook:00000000CC63759F18171E46835E96E44971FDFB07006446

In Excel, press CTRL-K in a cell, enter any text you want to be displayed, and paste that piece of code above (ex. outlook:123437654) at the address section. That’s it.

However it does not work with OFFICE 365. May you can help me?
KR Christian

Comment: 1. It is not clear to us - how you are creating hyperlink for Outlook Item. Can you please share screenshot to describe this process? We couldn't understand "left-click and lower right of the taskbar". What Outlook Client are you using for this? Windows, Mac, or Outlook on Web (Browser)?

2. Problem you are trying to solve is: how to paste this link correctly in Excel Sheet which is hosted in Office 365, is it?

Comment: For others stumbling on this unclear question: the OP posted in [this forum post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/creation-of-an-unique-link-to-an-outlook-e-mail/e798b237-6bf5-47c4-ada8-2527669f2a0c) how they get the GUID link.